# Wildfly Spring Boot a lot of NoClassDefFoundErrors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

i have a simple Spring Boot project i want to deploy on a Wildfly 26.1.3.Final server.
The project works fine in my IDE  (Eclipse) but when i deploy it i get a lot of NoClassDefFoundErrors.
It doesn't matter if i use Eclipse for the deployment or create a WAR-file with maven and deploy it with HAL Management Console in webbrowser.
I tried several things like including/excluding dependencies in POM, using different Wildfly versions (23,26,27) or adding jars from Spring-Framework as modules in Wildfly.

Can somebody help me to find and resolve the cause?

Here is part of the log (i can't post the whole log from deployment be:

```
2023-01-19 11:10:50,501 DEBUG [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Module deployment.ctrl-0.1.war defined by Service Module Loader
2023-01-19 11:10:50,505 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag in Module "deployment.ctrl-0.1.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment.ctrl-0.1.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.3.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.3.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.3.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.3.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2023-01-19 11:10:50,505 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag in Module "deployment.ctrl-0.1.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/LabelTag (Module "deployment.ctrl-0.1.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment.ctrl-0.1.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.3.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.3.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.3.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@26.1.3.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.xxx.ctrl</groupId>
    <artifactId>ctrl</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>ctrl</name>
    <description>Spring Boot project for creating Automation Control-files</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <release.number>17</release.number>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
                <!--<configuration>
                    <feature-pack-location>
            wildfly-preview@maven(org.jboss.universe:community-universe)#27.0.1.Final
        </feature-pack-location>
                    <layers>
                        <layer>jaxrs</layer>
                    </layers>
                    <plugin-options>
                        <jboss-fork-embedded>true</jboss-fork-embedded>
                    </plugin-options>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>-->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Edit:
Log when using Wildfly 27:

```
12:21:59,571 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ctrl-0.1.war".component."jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ctrl-0.1.war".component."jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.InjectionTargets.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargets.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet and jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener disagree on InnerClasses attribute
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1566)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.checkDeclaringClassLoadable(Reflections.java:427)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder.get(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getCastValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:177)
    ... 12 more

12:21:59,668 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ctrl-0.1.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ctrl-0.1.war\".component.\"jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet and jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener disagree on InnerClasses attribute"}}
12:21:59,727 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ctrl-0.1.war" (runtime-name : "ctrl-0.1.war")
12:21:59,728 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ctrl-0.1.war".component."jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
WFLYCTL0448: 3 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
```

Is this caused by different versions of depencies of my application and Wildfly?

Comment: `javax.*` vs. `jakarta.*` i think

Comment: My project uses jarkata and wildfly too?

Comment: I am not sure, but i think wildfly27 will be the first with `jakarta.*`

Comment: https://docs.wildfly.org/ do i interpret something wrong?

Comment: https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/WildFly_and_WildFly_Preview.html: `galleon.sh install wildfly-preview:current --dir=my-wildfly-server`

Comment: Ok, my mistake was i just looked at the table and not in the docs. For Wildfly 27 they write "beginning with the 27 release both standard WildFly and WildFly Preview support Jakarta EE 10". I tried with 27 and get another error. You can see in question.

Comment: *java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError* looks like the version spring is using is different from the one wildfly is using fro `jakarta.servlet`

Comment: The `IncompatibleClassChangeError` suggests that you have may have included an explicit dependency on jakarta-servlet API, instead of letting WildFly provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I change my POM to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.XXX.ctrl</groupId>
    <artifactId>ctrl</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>ctrl</name>
    <description>Spring Boot project for creating Automation Control-files</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <release.number>17</release.number>
        <deploy.wildfly.host>127.0.0.1</deploy.wildfly.host>
        <deploy.wildfly.port>9990</deploy.wildfly.port>
        <deploy.wildfly.username></deploy.wildfly.username>
        <deploy.wildfly.password></deploy.wildfly.password>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                    <hostname>${deploy.wildfly.host}</hostname>
                    <port>${deploy.wildfly.port}</port>
                    <username>${deploy.wildfly.username}</username>
                    <password>${deploy.wildfly.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The important part is (this removes the Tomcat from Spring Boot):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also add exlusion of logback-classic to avoid erros while deploying:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to find out, which dependencies use logback-classic.

I found the solution here https://dev.to/jakmar17/deploy-spring-boot-on-wildfly-application-server-2029

Thanks to Jens and Mark Rotteveel for helping!